# Can't checkout using svn from online server

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have downloaded and installed Slik SVN client from http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download.
Now I'm trying to download (checkout) WordPress sources and get error

```
>svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL'http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk': could not connect to server (http://core.svn.wordpress.org)
```

Running on Windows XP SP3, I'm not behind any VPN or proxy. The http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk url successfully opens in any browser.

Comment: Have you tried using any _other_ svn clients? TortoiseSVN is rather popular.

Comment: TortoiseSVN makes my explorer.exe to think much longer. I don't like it. I found and use DownloadSVN as temporary solution - http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

Comment: Most of what causes Explorer to slow down with TortoiseSVN is the auto-updating of icon indicators, which essentially is just a scanning process in the background. If you turn that process off (in the TortoiseSVN properties) it speeds up to "normal" speeds. My point though is to see if you can get the svn repo to check out using a different client to isolate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Check proxy setting in `...\Application Data\Subversion\servers` for source host

Comment: I haven't found Subversion folder in C:\Documents and Settings\

Comment: @d9k `c:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Subversion\servers` or use search on drive

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mark checkbox "search in hidded folders". So I found "servers" file in C:\Documents and Settings\d9k\Application Data\Subversion : http://pastie.org/3635328

Comment: @d9k - think, read docs, define special section for core.svn.wordpress.org, svn co with debug... **SEARCH ANSWER, YOU DONE NOTHING BY HAND!!!**

Comment: @d9k - nothing **must** be easy, *remote* troubleshooting - **never can**

Comment: @d9k - do you still have checkout error? Can you browse repo in ordinary web-browser?

Comment: > Can you browse repo in ordinary web-browser? - Of course, I can. Also DownloadSVN application works perfectly.